# Creating a country shaped button / picturebox

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I`m currently working on a project about states in my country, and I`m trying to create a map where you can click on a state and something happens (e.g. a question pops-up or information is shown once you click), but I just don`t know how to do it. I`ve tried to shape a button into a state, but the only possible shape is a rectangle, same with picture boxes. I`ve tried to search it up on google, but no success. So, is there any possible way to do it in Visual Studio, or do I need a 3rd party program? Thanks.

P.S.: Something like this https://mapchart.net/world.html
Edit: i`m using WinForms platform

Comment: What platform are you using? WinForms, WPF, UWP, Web?

Comment: Examples: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33478564/interactiveclickable-map/33480232#33480232), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25701778/make-a-map-of-buttons/25703170#25703170) and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28373615/create-custom-shape-for-button/28376826?r=SearchResults&s=3|23.2434#28376826)

Answer (score 0):

Coincidentally, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55987379/how-can-i-overlay-multiple-pngs-and-have-each-of-them-clickable-in-their-visible/55987538#55987538) is related to what you are trying to do!

Check out the code locally in firefox.

What you need is:
1x world map like that in the url
and many masks for each country.

You detect which country the user is hovering over/clicks by checking for the masks (white pixel).
Its the same approach as what I linked.

Comment: Thank you kindly, it looks pretty complicated, but it`s a huge help.